# one api returns: Method not allowed when sending webservice request

Tags: c#, api, rest, web-services

I have a working webservice running where I have just one api call, it works perfect.
So now I want to add another api but I cannot get this one to work, it keeps returning this error when I try in in a browser

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The
> inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for
> this resource

If I try it in my testclient c# project it returns `Method not allowed`

I am doing exact the same as in the already working api, so what can be the reason for this nasty error ?

code from the working api

```
public class SCSController : ApiController
{
    // GET: SCS
    public HttpResponseMessage AddDriverPayments(DriverPayment driverPayments)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;

            try
            {
                DriverPaymentResponse response = new DriverPaymentResponse() { PaymentID = driverPayments.newID, SCS_ID = driverPayments.sCS_ID };
                result = Request.CreateResponse(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("error"),
                    ReasonPhrase = ex.Message
                };
                throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

code from the not working api

```
    public class VLAController : ApiController
    {

        // GET: VLA
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAppLogin(AppLoginRequest appLoginRequest)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;

            try
            {
                //VLADataBase db = new VLADataBase();
                //AppLoginResponse response = db.GetAppLogin(appLoginRequest);
                AppLoginResponse response = new AppLoginResponse() { Authorized = true, TruckID = 123 };
                result = Request.CreateResponse(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("error"),
                    ReasonPhrase = "fout: " + ex.Message
                };
                throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

how I call it in my testclient

This is how I call the working api

```
  string JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payments);
            System.Net.Http.StringContent restContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(comboBoxEditWebService.Text, restContent);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    DriverPaymentResponse Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriverPaymentResponse>(stream);

                    textBoxResult.Text = Result.SCS_ID + " " + Result.PaymentID;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBoxResult.Text = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBoxResult.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

And this is how I call the not working api

```
   string JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appLoginRequest);
            System.Net.Http.StringContent restContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(comboBoxEdit1.Text, restContent);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    AppLoginResponse Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppLoginResponse>(stream);

                    textBox1.Text = Result.Authorized.ToString() + " " + Result.TruckID.ToString(); //Result.SCS_ID + " " + Result.PaymentID;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

I must note that both api's are in different units, in different controllers, maybe that can be a problem ?

[image]

So how can I get this solved so I can use both api's ?

Comment: What HTTP methods are your endpoints? I don't see it defined anywhere. However, you call `client.PostAsync()` in both methods to call API, which hints that both are defined as POST methods. But the `GetAppLogin`-name hints, that it may be a GET method? That could also explain, why it says "method now allowed".

Comment: @thesystem The `GetAppLogin` is just a name, it does not means it uses the `GET` method. I have not started this project and have no experience with webservices. How can I see how a method is defined as POST or GET ?

Comment: @thesystem Also do not forget that one method is working without problems for more than a year now, so I guess it is POST. But I can't find where this is set

Comment: Sorry, I am bit confused how it can work. In both methods, you make a completely empty HttpClient: `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`. At the very least, I would think you had to specify, where the HttpClient-call has to be directed to, by e.g. setting baseaddress (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?view=net-6.0). I think the project has a very unusual configuration (or more likely, one that I am unfamiliar with). Usually, a controller endpoint is decorated with for example `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`. Maybe different for webservice

Comment: Still, "method not allowed" could hint at calling a with wrong HTTP Method. Try to change the not working one to `client.GetAsync(...)`. You may have to edit parameters to conform with `GetAsync()`

Comment: @thesystem When I change it to `GetAsync` then I cannot include my `restContent` anymore. How does that works ? As I said before I am not the one that started this project I just got it on my desk today...

Comment: @thesystem Decorating the api with `[HttpPost]` did the trick, thank you. If you post this as answer I will accept it

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked. My assumption was wrong, and I am unsure where in your project it is defined, what HTTP method you are using in the endpoints, but I will post the answer for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorating the endpoint with `[HttpPost]` did the trick (see conversation in comments).